# Como "Hago" para que se vea todo el contenido del body de mi pagina web

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, responsive, html-tabla

estaba diseñando una pagina web (mientras aprendo), y he seguido unos tutoriales de YouTube para llegar a un "*responsive sidebar*", y luego quería poner el contenido del body el cual lo iba a formular con tablas, pero a la hora de insertar la tabla no se me muestra pero se me reconoce en la pagina web, y querría saber si alguno me podría ayudar a encontrar el error, adjunto codigo de html y css de la pagina web, muchas gracias desde ya.

```css
 /*Google Font Link */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karantina&dispay=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Karantina', Arial;
}
header{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 78px;
    background-color: #11101d;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
/* Gracias al script y cambiarle el "estado" de la clase al nav/search, lo que se hace es que una vez que el usuario clickea y se cambia el nav pasara a utilizar las propiedades que se definen en las proximas lineas de codigo*/
.sidebar.active{
    width: 240px;
    font-size: x-large;
}
.sidebar .logo_content .logo{
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
}
.sidebar.active .logo_content .logo{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.logo_content .logo i{
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    
}
.logo_content .logo .logo_name{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;   
}
.sidebar #btn{
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    top: 6px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    height:  50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.sidebar.active #btn{ 
    left: 90%;
}
.sidebar ul{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.sidebar ul li {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.sidebar ul li .tooltip{
    position: absolute;
    left: 122px;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 122px;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0s;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: x-large;
}
.sidebar.active ul li .tooltip{
    display: none;
}
.sidebar ul li:hover .tooltip{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50%;

}
/* Caja De Busqueda */
.sidebar ul li input{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 12px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: #1d1b31;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
}
/* En Esta Linea De Codigo Le tuvimos que dar un id al icono de busqueda dado que a la hora de llamar el selector por clases en el editor de codigo me saltaba erorr */
.sidebar ul li .bxs-search{
    position: absolute 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
}
.sidebar ul li .bxs-search:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color:#1d1b31;
}
.sidebar ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border-radius: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar ul li a:hover{
    color: #11101d;
    background-color: #fff;
    
}
/* Check A in this line */
.sidebar ul li i{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
}
.sidebar .links_name{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
}
.sidebar.active .links_name{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.home_content{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100%-78px);
    left: 78px;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
}
.home_content .text{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #1d1b31;
    margin: 12px;
}
.sidebar.active ~ .home_content{
    width: calc(100% - 240px);
    left: 240px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Author Mateo  -->
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
        <!-- Link CDN Boxicons -->
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <title>Responsive SideBar Menu</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <!-- Este div funciona a modo de nav dado que dentro del mismo tendremos distintos divs a modo de "contenedores" en los cuales dividiremos uno para el logo de "GitHub" y el titulo de Menu, luego empezaremos con una lista desordenada en la que iran los "hipervinculos" a las otras paginas en conjunto con el logo ilustrativo y su respectivo nombre de la funcion-->
            <nav> 
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <div class="logo_content">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <i class='bx bx-code'></i> 
                            <div class="logo_name">¿Learn Programming?</div>
                        </div>
                        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav_list">
                        <!-- La Barra De Busqueda Search al no ser muy funcional no la usaremos
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class='bx bxs-search'></i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                            </a>
                        El Span es una etiqueta que se utiliza de modo similar al div, con la diferencia de que el div es un elemento de bloque mientras que el span es un elemento en linea y poco contenido en el contenedor 
                            <span class="tooltip">Search</span> -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class='bx bx-home' ></i>
                                <span class="links_name">Home</span>
                            </a>
                            <span class="tooltip">Home</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class='bx bx-book'></i>
                                <span class="links_name">History</span>
                            </a>
                            <span class="tooltip">History</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class='bx bx-terminal'></i>
                                <span class="links_name">Fundamentos</span>
                            </a>
                            <span class="tooltip">Fundamentos</span> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class='bx bxl-python' ></i>
                                <span class="links_name">Learn Python Basic</span>
                            </a>
                            <span class="tooltip">Learn Python Basic</span> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="home_content">
                    <div class="text">¿Que Es La Programacion?</div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <article>
            <section>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hola Mundo</td>
                        <td>Prueba Tablas</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
        </article>
    
        
        <!-- Script Para El Side Bar, esta funcion lo que hace es canmbiar el estado del sidebar, a "sidebar active"-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
            let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
            let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".bxs-search");
            btn.onclick = function(){
                sidebar.classList.toggle("active");
            }
            searchBtn.onclick = function(){
                sidebar.classList.toggle("active");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: Se reconoce la primera columna pero quiero "traerla" mas a la derecha y abajo]

PD: Luego De Probar he visto que la tabla me la toma sin margin y padding porque lo he puesto no me había dado cuenta, querría saber si alguno tendría idea de como solucionarlo, nuevamente muchas gracias y saludos.`

Answer (score 0):

De la manera en que tienes estructurada la página para que te salga en el lugar que quieres, todo el contenido de tu página debes agregarlo dentro del div con clase `home_content`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```css
/*Google Font Link */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karantina&dispay=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Karantina', Arial;
}
header{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 78px;
    background-color: #11101d;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
/* Gracias al script y cambiarle el "estado" de la clase al nav/search, lo que se hace es que una vez que el usuario clickea y se cambia el nav pasara a utilizar las propiedades que se definen en las proximas lineas de codigo*/
.sidebar.active{
    width: 240px;
    font-size: x-large;
}
.sidebar .logo_content .logo{
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
}
.sidebar.active .logo_content .logo{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.logo_content .logo i{
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    
}
.logo_content .logo .logo_name{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;   
}
.sidebar #btn{
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    top: 6px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    height:  50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.sidebar.active #btn{ 
    left: 90%;
}
.sidebar ul{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.sidebar ul li {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.sidebar ul li .tooltip{
    position: absolute;
    left: 122px;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 122px;
    background: #fff;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0s;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: x-large;
}
.sidebar.active ul li .tooltip{
    display: none;
}
.sidebar ul li:hover .tooltip{
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50%;

}
/* Caja De Busqueda */
.sidebar ul li input{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 12px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: #1d1b31;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
}
/* En Esta Linea De Codigo Le tuvimos que dar un id al icono de busqueda dado que a la hora de llamar el selector por clases en el editor de codigo me saltaba erorr */
.sidebar ul li .bxs-search{
    position: absolute 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
}
.sidebar ul li .bxs-search:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color:#1d1b31;
}
.sidebar ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border-radius: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.sidebar ul li a:hover{
    color: #11101d;
    background-color: #fff;
    
}
/* Check A in this line */
.sidebar ul li i{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
}
.sidebar .links_name{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
}
.sidebar.active .links_name{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.home_content{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100%-78px);
    left: 78px;
    transition: all 0.5 ease;
}
.home_content .text{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #1d1b31;
    margin: 12px;
}
.sidebar.active ~ .home_content{
    width: calc(100% - 240px);
    left: 240px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Author Mateo  -->
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
        <!-- Link CDN Boxicons -->
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <title>Responsive SideBar Menu</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav> 
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <div class="logo_content">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <i class='bx bx-code'></i> 
                            <div class="logo_name">¿Learn Programming?</div>
                        </div>
                        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav_list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class='bx bx-home' ></i>
                                <span class="links_name">Home</span>
                            </a>
                            <span class="tooltip">Home</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class='bx bx-book'></i>
                                <span class="links_name">History</span>
                            </a>
                            <span class="tooltip">History</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class='bx bx-terminal'></i>
                                <span class="links_name">Fundamentos</span>
                            </a>
                            <span class="tooltip">Fundamentos</span> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class='bx bxl-python' ></i>
                                <span class="links_name">Learn Python Basic</span>
                            </a>
                            <span class="tooltip">Learn Python Basic</span> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="home_content">
                    <div class="text">¿Que Es La Programacion?</div>
                   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                   
                   <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hola Mundo</td>
                        <td>Prueba Tablas</td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </table>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <article>
            <section>
             . 
               
            </section>
        </article>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
            let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
            let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".bxs-search");
            btn.onclick = function(){
                sidebar.classList.toggle("active");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```